# Email Python Script Output

Tags: python, email, web-scraping

I just finished creating my first news web scraping script and I am quite content with it even though the code does not look nice at all. I was  wondering how I should go about sending the output of the script to myself via email (gmail address) when I run it. I tried to run smtplib, but it's not working for me.

Here is my current code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from datetime import date
from dateutil import parser
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

my_url1 = "https://www.coindesk.com/category/business-news/legal"
my_url2 = "https://cointelegraph.com/tags/bitcoin-regulation"
my_url3 = "https://techcrunch.com/tag/blockchain/"

# Opening up the website, grabbing the page
uFeedOne = uReq(my_url1, timeout=5)
page_one = uFeedOne.read()
uFeedOne.close()

# html parser
page_soup1 = soup(page_one, "html.parser")

# grabs each publication block
containers_one = page_soup1.findAll("a", {"class": "stream-article"} )

for container_one in containers_one:
  ## get todays date.
  ## I have taken an offset as the site has older articles than today.
  today = date.today().strftime("%Y, %m, %d")

  ## The actual datetime string is in the datetime attribute of the time tag.
  date_time1 = container_one.time['datetime']

  ## The dateutil package parses the ISO-formatted date and returns a condensed version.
  date1 = parser.parse(date_time1)
  dt1 = date1.strftime("%Y, %m, %d")

  ## Simple comparison
  if dt1 == today:
      link1 = container_one.attrs['href']
      publication_date1 = "published on " + container_one.time.text
      title1 = container_one.h3.text
      description1 = "(CoinDesk)-- " +  container_one.p.text

      print("link: " + link1)
      print("publication_date: " + publication_date1)
      print("title: ", title1)
      print("description: " + description1 + " \n")


uFeedTwo = uReq(my_url2, timeout=5)
page_two = uFeedTwo.read()
uFeedTwo.close()

page_soup2 = soup(page_two, "html.parser")

containers_two = page_soup2.findAll("div",{"class": "post-preview-item-inline__content"})

for container_two in containers_two:
  today = date.today().strftime("%Y, %m, %d")

  date_time2 = container_two.time['datetime']
  date2 = parser.parse(date_time2)
  dt2 = date2.strftime("%Y, %m, %d")

  title_container2 = container_two.find("span",{"class": "post-preview-item-inline__title"})
  description_container2 = container_two.find("p",{"class": "post-preview-item-inline__text"}).text

  if dt2 == today:
    link2 = container_two.div.a.attrs['href']
    publication_date2 = "published on " + date2.strftime("%b %d, %Y")
    title2 = title_container2.text
    description2 = "(CoinTelegraph)-- " + description_container2

    print("link: " + link2)
    print("publication_date: " + publication_date2)
    print("title: ", title1)
    print("description: " + description2 + " \n")


uFeedThree = uReq(my_url3, timeout=5)
page_three = uFeedThree.read()
uFeedThree.close()

# html parser
page_soup3 = soup(page_three, "html.parser")

# grabs each publication block
containers_three = page_soup3.findAll("div",{"class": "post-block post-block--image post-block--unread"})

for container_three in containers_three:
  today = date.today().strftime("%Y, %m, %d")
  date_time3 = container_three.time['datetime']

  date3 = parser.parse(date_time3)
  dt3 = date3.strftime("%Y, %m, %d")

  keyword1 = "law"
  keyword2 = "legal"
  description_container3 = container_three.find("div", {"class": "post-block__content"}).text.strip()

  if dt3 == today and (keyword2 in description_container3) or (keyword1 in description_container3):
      link3 = container_three.header.h2.a.attrs['href']
      publication_date3 = "published on " +  date3.strftime("%b %d, %Y")
      title3 = container_three.header.h2.a.text.strip()
      description3 = "(TechCrunch)-- " + description_container3

      print("link: " + link3)
      print("publication_date: " + publication_date3)
      print("title: ", title3)
      print("description: " + description3 + " \n")
```

I understand that I am suppose to do a variation of this:

```
# Open a plain text file for reading.  For this example, assume that
# the text file contains only ASCII characters.
with open(textfile) as fp:
    # Create a text/plain message
    msg = MIMEText(fp.read())

# me == the sender's email address
# you == the recipient's email address
msg['Subject'] = 'The contents of %s' % textfile
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

# Send the message via our own SMTP server.
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.send_message(msg)
s.quit()
```

Comment: what issue are you facing

Comment: @Jeril he is having issue to mail the output of the script... most probably with the SMTPlib configuration..

Comment: If you have issue with the email sending, the web scraping part of your code is tottally irrelevant, just like the tag. Also, please explicitly specify your problem!

Comment: I would like to send this to myself and I don’t know how.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code snippet to send a mail to anyone using SMTP.

> Below code is configured for gmail SMT P.If you have any other it can
>   be configred.

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = 'me@gmail.com'
msg['To'] = 'you@gmail.com'
msg['Subject'] = 'Enter subjecy of msg here'
message = 'here is the email'
msg.attach(MIMEText(message))

# GMAIL_SMTP_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
# GMAIL_SMTP_PORT = '587'
mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
# secure our email with tls encryption
mailserver.starttls()
mailserver.sendmail('me@gmail.com','you@gmail.com',msg.as_string())
mailserver.quit()
```